# dojox/mobile/Carousel stop navigation on clicking pageIndicators

Tags: javascript, dojo

Widget: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/Carousel.html

I would like to stop carousel from navigating to the next pane when clicking the pageIndicator (dots).

I don't want to hide the pageIndicator with the styles rather want to stop the event.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to set your own onClick handler on the PageIndicator and make sure it does nothing and returns `false`. That way the original action will be ignored.